# Did China do anything to prevent its citizens from traveling to South Korea other than banning its travel agencies from selling package tours?

Tags: china, south-korea

After South Korea implemented the THAAD system, [the number of Chinese tourists has dropped significantly](http://english.yonhapnews.co.kr/business/2017/08/22/0501000000AEN20170822009300320.html).

> The tally of Chinese visitors came to 281,263 last month, down 69.3 percent from 917,519 recorded the previous year, according to the data by the Korea Tourism Organization (KTO).
>
> The number of Chinese visitors in the January-July period stood at 2.53 million, a 46.5 percent drop from 4.73 million tallied in 2016, it said..

The article also writes the following:

> The sharp decline in Chinese tourists has been widely expected as Beijing has banned its travel agencies from selling package tours to Korea since mid-March in apparent retaliation over Seoul's deployment of the U.S. Terminal High Altitude Area Defense (THAAD) system.

However, I wonder if this is the only policy China did to prevent its citizens from traveling to South Korea. I'm not sure that just banning its travel agencies from selling package tours could lead to the sharp decline, even though it might be plausible that most Chinese people use travel agencies to travel to South Korea due to the visa policy.

Is this the only policy China did to prevent its citizens from traveling to South Korea?

Comment: A good way to know would be able to tell how much more you need to pay for a travel to South Korea

Comment: From my experience of leaving currently in South Korea, I can tell that it is more common for Chinese people to travel in group or organized tour than in EU or USA. I cannot assert that it is the only reason for the decline though.

Comment: The vast majority of Chinese tourists travel as part of travel groups. There's no need to look much further.